# how generate Sacffold or crud with spring web mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, crud

I can how to generate CRUD or scaffold in Spring MVC, some example of website?

you have some command to generate scaffold?

I have programmed with the Framework Phalcon php, and Phalcon there is a series of commands to generate the scaffold or crud, but in JAVA with spring web mvc I can not do it, have any idea or example of how it could start?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring boot or the web initializer ([here](http://start.spring.io/)).
In there you can go to the 'switch to full veersion' and select Spring MVC. This will generate a skeleton project for you with Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

I am really want to share a tool in Github named  [Sloth -  https://github.com/coolcooldee/sloth](https://github.com/coolcooldee/sloth) !

It has several features：

```
1.Generate Model–View–Controller Code
2.Generate CRUD  Code
3.Generate API DOC
4.Provide Many Kinds Of Data Access With JDBC ：Mybatis、JOOQ、Spring JDBC
```